# Will ElasticSearch performance differ if we have multiple nested queries

Tags: elasticsearch

In general, if we need to do an OR condition in elasticsearch within one nested type, let's say, we do query like below :

**Query 1:**

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "bool": {
                  "should": [{
                    "match": {
                      "descTags.device": {
                        "query": "abc"
                      }
                    }
                  }, {
                    "match": {
                      "descTags.device": {
                        "query": "xyz"
                      }
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }]
            }
          },
          "path": "descTags"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query has one nested and have OR condition within this one nested type.

Representing below the same query with two nested blobs :

**Query 2:**

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [{
                        "match": {
                          "descTags.Modality": {
                            "query": "abc"
                          }
                        }
                      }]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "descTags",
                }
              }]
            }
          }, {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [{
                        "match": {
                          "descTags.Modality": {
                            "query": "xyz"
                          }
                        }
                      }]
                    }
                  },
                  "path": "descTags"
                }
              }]
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Will there be any difference in performance between query1 and query2 just because we are having nested blob multiple times?

EDIT 1:
As per the below comments (@kamal), I am simplifying my question here..

Will there be any difference in performance if the boolean operation is done between "attributes that belong to same nested type, declaring the nested type only once" vs "attributes that belong to same nested type, declaring the nested type twice, once for each attribute".

like below :

1.

```
nested : 
     or : 
         attribute1
         attribute2
```

vs

2.

```
or :
     nested : 
        attribute1
     nested :
        attribute2
```

Comment: *What do you think is more readable for humans*, is also an important point. Isn't it? ;)

Comment: @Kamal, Edited the question for you.

Comment: hey that's not what I meant. I was asking w.r.t the `main` queries you've posted. First one is more readable isn't it. Why do you think second one is important. Do not simply find solutions in the name of performance. Look for something simple. Best solutions are often coded in simple manner firstly. Something if someone reads it, they'll understand it precisely.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but your comment doesn't make sense to me. I am using Syntax tree to build my queries dynamically. According to our needs, we are able to achieve the second query formation but not the first. So making sure, if there is going to be the performance difference by any chance.

Comment: Before the matches happen, first thing ES would do is parse the query itself. If you look at the tree structure, there will be difference in time it takes to parse the query structure due to additional bool logic there being. Internally (although not sure) then the query might be converted/optimized into the similar ones resulting in more or less similar execution time post parsing. However I'd suggest you refer to this link, to do some search query analysis to understand the difference in execution times of both queries. https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries

Comment: Hey, @Deepak. Did you find an answer to your question? I have the same question, but can't find any recommendations.